# error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'. Is Observable contains json propery?

Tags: arrays, typescript, mapping, observable, angular5

I get compilation error: `TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'`when trying to mapped json on complex object`Model.SearchResult.RootObject` 
It is happens in `res.json()` of the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ResultPrice} from '../models/result-prices.model';
import { BaseService } from '../shared-components/base-service/base.service';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as Model from '../models/results.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class SearchResultService {
    private apiUrl = 'http://someurl/api/SearchResult/';


    constructor(public http: HttpClient ) {
    }

    getSearchResultTable(hash: number): Observable<Model.SearchResult.RootObject> {
        let tmp = this.http.get('http://someurl/api/SearchResult/123')
        .map(res => {
            return res.json().results.map(item => {
                return new Model.SearchResult.RootObject();
          });
        });
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Is `Observable` contains `json` propery or not? Maybe I missed some `import`?

Comment: Are you in Angular5?

Comment: Yes in Angular5.

Comment: Normally, with httpClient .json() is not util. In your case res is the body of the response (https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-angular5/). Maybe try to delete .json().results

Comment: If i delete it how can I mapped json that returned from server to client object? In my case it is class.

Comment: I don't have a computer to verify, but you can directly use map on res: (res => res.map(item => new Model.SearchResult.RootObject())

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving map's first argument `res` a type. Like so ->

```
return this.http.get('http://someurl/api/SearchResult/123')
  .map(res: any) => {
    return res.json().results.map(item => {
      return new Model.SearchResult.RootObject();
    });
  });
```